# CORS for HTML5 Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, cors, hybrid

I have read lot of things about CORS and how allowing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is security vulnerability to web server. But none of the article explained about how we can allow HTML5 hybrid application to access web services hosted on some domain which disallowed the wildcard char *

My question is: as far as my knowledge HTML5 hybrid app does not run on any specific domain that can we set as a whitelisted domain at the Access-Control-Allow-Origin lists. Then how we can still access the web service data from the hybrid APP request data through ajax call over web server which disallowing * under Access-Control-Allow-Origin tag?

Comment: [`JSONP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: @MayankSharma Did you find a solution for your question? I would like to know how you resolve this. I have the same concern. Would you mind sharing it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When running on a device, your app will run in the browser, but will run from the local filesystem (from a location similar to file://path/to/index.html). Therefore, an origin does not exist. The browser will not do any preflight OPTIONS request, nor will it block calls to the API because of cross origin issues, simply because there is no origin.

For this reason, you can configure your server to only allow same origin requests, to keep things secure. Calls made from the device will still be allowed. However, when you run your app in the browser on your local dev machine (for testing purposes), you might run into CORS issues, because in this case there *is* an origin. You can solve this by allowing your local domain to access the API (remember to remove it in production), by using a browser plugin to disable CORS, or by using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have build a lot of hybrid apps using phonegap, jquery and ajax.  You can set your CORS in php files or in .htaccess files as follow and it will work.

For .htaccess file use this

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Alternatively, you can integrate the code below at very first top of all .php files to be access via cross domain.
Just know that  symbol * makes all domain accessible as well

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
?>
```

Comment: That was my concern, I don't want to allow all domain accessible to this. Can't we avoid using * and restrict to other specific value here?

Comment: Also  you "Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late. Okay either of the code below will do it for you.  give me a shout if you are still having issues
Thanks

```
in .htaccess file

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com


or in php



header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com");
```

Comment: Hello, I can't set any particular domain here as it not be executed from any domain. May be I was unclear with the question. Let me rephrase it. My app is combination of HTML/JS/CSS bundled through phonegap to .APK. This APK is as good as any android APP. This will run over mobile device using their webview. Anybody can download this APK and run from their device. So technically its not running on any domain that can be mentioned at the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your app is a static one right. its not hosted online right. your app is not making any ajax, jquery or json call to the server right. the app is not making any database call to a remote server right. if your app is not making any call to any of the above remotely then there is no need to be bothered about cross domain.

Okay am asking you another question? when you click a url link in your app, does it work by taking you to the intended page. what happened.

Comment: APP is not static, it is dynamic and interacting with server using AJAX over Restful APIs. So CORS is my concern.